# If cats were introduced too quickly, can the process be started over?

Tags: cats, introducing-pets, bonding

I messed up and introduced a new female 7 yr old cat to my male 8 yr old cat.. They were  doing  fairly well, a few  hisses but tolerating each other for the first few days, then my husband was sitting on the  chair and the new female  jumped up into  his lap, and  our male came into the  room. He is very attached to  my  husband, often  not  leaving  his side when he is in bed on days  when he is not well.. 
After seeing the female with my husband my male cat aggressively  tried to  attack the female.

I have them  separated now. but I am afraid of what will  happen  to the   little  female, if we were  to  leave them alone and accessible to each other..

Can I re-introduce them    very  slowly and maybe have this work?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can reintroduce them!
It can be a very lengthy process though, but I'm sure you know that.

1. Begin by keeping them separated as you have. Idealy so that they
   cannot see eachother. Have them eat their favourite food on
   different sides of the door as close to the door as possible without
   haveing them react negatively. Sideswapping can also be good (that is switch the sides of the cats every now and then so they both own the entire home).
2. When they are comfortable with eachothers smells, exchange the door for something 
   seethrouch. Like a net-door or something similar. Go
   through the same process as in 1. Add some playtime while both cats can see eachother. Continue till the cats are comfortable.
3. When they are comfortable with eachother on different sides of a seethrough barriere let them have supervised visits with eachother. When you feel they are comfortable with eachother without showing any kind of agression you can let them live together.

This is the geist of it but a bit simplified. Positive pheromones can help. I don't know what is available to you, but something like feliway can help http://www.feliway.com/

For more details I can reccomend reading something by Jackson Galaxy or watch his show My Cat From Hell