# Got a new second cat. previous cat is not happy

Tags: cats

I have a 4 month old cat and now I got a second kitten. They don't really like each other. My first cat hisses at the new kitten at eye contact and the kitten hides in a corner next to the closet. I have already separated them and given the kitten some time to get used to the room. Later the old cat came along and doesn't seem aggressive to her. She does her own thing as usual only as soon as she sees the new cat, the hissing starts again and the kitten hides. But from the first cat comes no aggression, only hissing and a look of death (no hump either).

The problem now is that I can't keep the two cats away from each other any longer, because I only have one litter box and I always have to seal one off.

Furthermore, I noticed that my first cat also starts to hiss at my hands after my hand has taken on the smell of the new cat. My first cat also hisses at the corner where the new cat was hiding, even though she wasn't there at the time.

seperated, both cats are very calm. Both are female.

Currently I am still on vacation so I can with the cats but when I have to work again I am afraid that the new kitten will have to hide my entire working time in the corner next to the closet from fear.

My question to you would be:

What can I do to get both cats used to each other with currently only one litter box? What do I do when I am going to sleep today?

Comment: also https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/recommendations-for-introducing-adult-cats-to-newly-adopted-adult-cats https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6610/if-cats-were-introduced-too-quickly-can-the-process-be-started-over

Comment: Note that while these reference adult cats, kittens also may need to go through an introduction period. So get another litterbox, separate them, and introduce them slowly using the techniques in the related questions.